# How to update TTL for dead letter existing queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Not able to update existing TTL for particular Queue

Got some command but it will be for all queue.

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy TTL ".*" '{"message-ttl":60000}' --apply-to queues
```

I need to update only for one Queue. Please help

Comment: No... I just need to update existing x-message-ttl for deadletterqueue(Name is : deadLetterQueue) How to update?

Comment: Nothing is happening ...